# When the application encourters a long name file, the process dies

Tags: java, android, linux

the code goes:

```
android.util.Log.i("QRDFileExplorer","loadDir().before=feaffdsafdsf");
String[] names=f.list();
android.util.Log.i("QRDFileExplorer","loadDir().string names=");
```

The codes go well at the most of time, but if there is a file that has a long file name (more than 90 chinese characters, which is about 180 bytes) under a directory, then when it comes to `f.list()`, the entire process dies without throwing any exception.

logcat:

```
04-10 16:46:49.129: I/QRDFileExplorer(16413): loadDir().before=feaffdsafdsf
04-10 16:46:49.129: A//system/bin/app_process(16413): stack corruption detected: aborted
04-10 16:46:49.149: E/COREDUMP(16500): /sdcard1/coredump Read-only file system
04-10 16:46:49.159: I/WindowState(586): WIN DEATH: Window{41920440 com.android.qrdfileexplorer/com.android.qrdfileexplorer.QRDFileExplorer paused=false}
04-10 16:46:49.159: I/ActivityManager(586): Process com.android.qrdfileexplorer (pid 16413) has died.
04-10 16:46:49.169: W/ActivityManager(586): Force removing ActivityRecord{416bd738 com.android.qrdfileexplorer/.QRDFileExplorer}: app died, no saved state
04-10 16:46:49.239: W/InputMethodManagerService(586): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 16413 uid 10017
```

The `android.util.Log.i("QRDFileExplorer","loadDir().string names=");` log is not printed, so it must be a matter of `String[] names=f.list();`, I belive the code is right, we all do this way to list the files, so it is a problem about the phone plat right? It is something about the memory or else. Anyone who knows more about this and how to resolve this for at least to give user a warning other than to shut down suddenly.

Comment: Now I know, in the UTF-8 encode, a Chinese character may occupy 3 bytes, so the encode bytes for 90 Hanzi are more than 255 bytes. And Linux has a filename limit for no more than 255 bytes, so the file name has exceed the limit, but how to resolve this problem?  Or just let it be, cause Linux has already limited the length

Comment: Does it work in emulator?

Comment: I tested this in emulator but failed, cause when I push a file that contains Chinese characters in file name, it turns to unreadable code. I tested on HTC Desire S, the file explore just ignore the long name files. So, it's something about the libcore. about the filename limit in java_io_File.cpp file. I will still trace on this.